# How do I store response object into a global variable

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to store the response coming from my socket connection in a global array variable to plot a graph, how can i achieve that

```
var socket = io('heart sensor api call');
var getValue = function () {
    socket.on('connect', function () {});
    socket.emit('get data', 'hello');
    socket.on('reply', function (data) {
        heart_rate = data;

    });
}
```

Comment: Are you essentially trying to figure out how to return the response from an asynchronous call?

Comment: I am trying to store the data coming from an api call into my global array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Do you get any errors? On which line?

Comment: No errors i am getting the data correctly, just want to store them outside the function scope to use for later time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express. You could create `global.heart_rate = ...`  it will create a global variable accessible from every where. As this is not recommended, I would suggest looking in to `app.locals`. Hope this helps.